# If $\text{adj}A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1&0\\2&3&1\\2&1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\text{adj}(2A)$ is $2^k\text{adj}(A)$, find $k$

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have thought of a solution for this, but I know it’s wrong. I don’t know what’s wrong with the procedure, I just solved it instinctively.

$$\text{adj} A =A^{-1}|A|$$

So for $2A$

$$\text{adj} 2A =(2A)^{-1} |2A|$$

$$=\frac 12 A 4 |A|$$
$$=2\text{adj} A$$

Which implies $k=1$

As I said, the answer is wrong, I am aware of that. The question remains: what’s wrong with my procedure and how do I get the correct answer.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you conclude that $|2A|=4|A|$?

Comment: ah thats where you're wring my friend. What you have used is for |adj(A)|

Comment: @Aditya that was the problem. What is the determinant of $|k\cdot I|$? Notice that it is multiplication of the diagonal.

Comment: @Phicar yes, I blame my memory for that. $k^{n-1}$ applies in case of adjudicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, $\det(mA) = m^n \det A$ where $m \in \mathbb R$. So the answer should really be $$(2A )^{-1} |2A| = \frac 12 A^{-1} \ 2^3 |A| = 4 \  \text{adj} (A) $$

Comment: you mean $(2A)^{-1}$ right?

Comment: @sai-kartik Yes, fixed.

Comment: So is this the right procedure every single time? I am a bit skeptical about the ‘substituting of 2A instead of A part’

Comment: @Aditya It is right. You can see that multiplying a matrix by a scalar $k$ multiplies every element inside it by that scalar. Take the determinant and notice that every row will contribute to a factor of $k$, i.e. the net result will be multiplying the determinant by $k^n$.